# Заменить Dictionary<Enum, ISomeClass> на IoC контейнер с DI

Tags: c#, inversion-of-control, рефакторинг

Есть следующий код, который хранит в себе экземпляры, реализующих 1 интерфейс, классов и по запросу выдаёт нужный, в зависимости от ключа ( он тут типа string, но я заменил на enum ). Это нужно мне для того, что бы было удобно хранить и получать доступ к единым экземплярам классов для разных частей программы ( синглтон ). Возможно ли такой код заменить с использованием  IoC контейнера с DI

```
public interface ISameClass
{
    int Value { get; set; }
    void DoStuff();
}

public class SameClass : ISameClass
{
    int Value { get; set; }
    void DoStuff()
    {
    //Do something
    }
}

public class SameClassProvider
{
        private readonly Dictionary<string, ISameClass> _sameClasses;

        public SameClassProvider(string parentDir)
        {
            _sameClasses = new Dictionary<string, ISameClass>
            {
                { "Type1", new SameClass() },
                { "Type2", new SameClass() },
                { "Type3", new SameClass() }
            };
        }

        public bool AddClass(string type, ISameClass class)
        {
            if (_sameClasses.ContainsKey(type) || class == null)
            {
                return false;
            }

            _nodes.Add(type, class);
            return true;

        }

        public ISameClass GetClass(string type)
        {
            if (_sameClasses.TryGetValue(type, out var someClass))
            {
                return someClass;
            }
        }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Конечно можно. 
Например, у нас есть интерфейс и классы

```
public interface II
{
    void SayHello();
}

public class AClass: II
{
    public void SayHello() => Console.WriteLine(nameof(AClass));
}

public class BClass : II
{
    public void SayHello() => Console.WriteLine(nameof(BClass));
}
```

В примерах я покажу, как делать это с Unity контейнером. 
Если вы хотите зарегистрировать инстансы, вы можете дать им имена

```
var container = new UnityContainer();

container.RegisterInstance<II>("AClass", new AClass());
container.RegisterInstance<II>("BClass", new BClass());

container.Resolve<II>("AClass").SayHello();
container.Resolve<II>("BClass").SayHello();
```

Вывод

```
AClass
BClass
```

вы также можете поступить, если надо зарегистрировать тип

```
var container = new UnityContainer();

container.RegisterType<II,AClass >("AClass");
container.RegisterType<II,BClass >("BClass");

container.Resolve<II>("AClass").SayHello();
container.Resolve<II>("BClass").SayHello();
```

Вывод аналогичен

```
AClass
BClass
```